# Calling RDS (SQL Server) resource running in first AWS account by the other AWS account using Lambda in node Js or Python

Tags: sql-server, amazon-iam

I have two AWS accounts, a RDS (SQL Server) is running in account2, I want to access/query this database from my account1 using lambda (node JS and Python). I am getting the following error:

> "errorMessage": "2019-07-05T13:59:46.698Z c13376bb-7c39-4036-8c34-67be3a5fbb34 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"

1. I have set up a Lambda in account1 to access the DB and able connect to a database which is on cloud (not on AWS) but unable to connect to the db on my AWS account1(<

   I created a RDS (SQL Server) on AWS account2 and able to connect the DB with SQL Server Management Studio.

I am using the following Lambda to connect to the RDS (SQL Server) database which is running is AWS account2.

I am expecting a row (any returned value) from the RDS running in AWS account2.

Comment: How is the function authenticating to the database? It should be using database credentials, which have nothing to do with AWS. Therefore, it doesn't matter than you are connect to a database in a different AWS Account. Try increasing the timeout on the Lambda function to see if it helps. This could be a Security Group issue -- can you edit your question to show or explain the security group configuration on the database?

Comment: Thanks John, I have added the DB endpoint with all the required access details in the lambda, I have tried the same lambda for other DB(Not on AWS) and I am able to access the other DB.  Even I can access the same RDS using SQL Management studio from my computer.  I have created Roles and policies but not sure how to configure the authentication between these two accounts.  Below is the Lambda code...

Comment: var sql = require("mssql");
 console.log("connected52");
 var dbConfig=
{
  server:"deogawandemssql.c2innkll6fph.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 
  user:"XXXXXXX",//
  password:"XXXXX",// 
  database: "XXXXXX"//
};

Comment: exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  callback(null,"fggfgffggf");
  var con = sql.connect(dbConfig, function(err) {
    console.log("connected");
      if (err) 
      console.log(err);
       var request = new sql.Request();

       request.query("select * from IVR.CallInfo", function(err, recordset) 
    {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      callback(err,recordset);
    });
    callback(err,"Test End");
    
  });
  sql.on('error',function(errs){
    callback(null,errs)
  });

  callback(null,"eow")
};

Comment: If you wish to include code, please Edit the question rather than adding it in a comment. Also, please edit your question to clarify what you are wanting to do, and what difficulty you are currently facing, since you seem to have solved the initial problem.